# How do you format equations in MLA?

Tags: formatting, mla

I'm currently writing an acedemic paper on the topic of computation time. I have to include several equations similar to the following:

> O(N<sup>2</sup>)

I am wondering if there is any special formatting or citing I would have to do for the above equation if I am writing this paper in MLA style.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about how/if you need to *cite* these equations, or how to *format* these equations (the latter would be dependent on what word processor you are using, not what citation style you are using)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a set of rules to go by when writing equations into an academic paper. Depending on the kind of equation, it'll be one of three types:

- In-line equations
- Displayed, but unnumbered, equations
- Displayed and numbered equations

In this case, O(N<sup>2</sup>) is an In-line equation. Given that, the only changes to be done would be to *italicize* the characters 'O' and 'N'. Rather than writing out O(N<sup>2</sup>), you should instead use *O*(*N*<sup>2</sup>).

For further reading on this topic, a useful PDF can be found [here](https://www.latech.edu/graduate_school/thesis_dissertations/coes_equation_guidelines.pdf).